# How to download latest file in folder using SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have folder in FTP Server.

The name of the folder is TEST. The Folder have many excel files, the file name have created

date. Eg: File name like

> Servicedata_01-10-11.xls
>
> Servicedata_05-10-11.xls
>
> Servicedata_07-10-11.xls
>
> Servicedata_15-10-11.xls

I have to download latest date file from the folder using SSIS.

Eg: Servicedata_15-10-11.xls

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script:

```
public void Main()
{
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(Dts.Variables["User::VarFolderPath"].Value.ToString());

    FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
    DateTime lastModified = DateTime.MinValue;

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        if (file.LastWriteTime > lastModified)
        {
            lastModified = file.LastWriteTime;
            Dts.Variables["User::VarFileName"].Value = file.ToString();
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::VarFileName"].Value.ToString());

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1- Create a **variable** for Latest File Path.

2- Using **Script Task** for determine the last files and then update the variable:
you must write some C# or VB code in Script Task for finding last file and then [update the variable](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/using-sql-server-2005-integration-services-variables-from-a-script-task/666).

3- Using **FTP Task** component to download the File from variable path.

Comment: Do yo know C# or VB programming?

Comment: The first and third steps are clear but if you can't write required C# code for second step ask it in new question.